# Permission denied /var/run/docker.sock when running docker from docker

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I have a container inside which I need to use another container (the first container holds my build env, and some of the projects are built by creating a container). I read about avoiding docker-in-docker, and followed the advice here: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ So I run the container like this:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -ti 6519bf891fee bash`

This is what I get, trying to run docker hello-world inside the container:

```
root@345cf0f934c3:/# docker run hello-world
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Moreover, trying `cat /var/run/docker.sock` results in:

```
cat: /var/run/docker.sock: No such device or address
```

Although `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`:

```
srw-rw----. 1 root root 0 Nov 29 11:58 /var/run/docker.sock
```

I am running as root both in the host and in the container, and have added the docker user to sudoers group in both. E.g. inside the container:

```
srw-rw----. 1 root root 0 Nov 29 08:58 /var/run/docker.sock
sudo:x:27:build,docker
```

Comment: Try this way `docker run -v /var/run/:/var/run -ti alpine /bin/sh`. Mapping path, not the file.

Comment: I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: run docker with `--privileged=true`

Comment: It didn't work, ls -l docker.sock is stil showing nobody nogroup in the container

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am trying to solve the same problem!